Piping calculated values into form fields for API data pull (calculated fields/text box w/ @CALCTEXT)
I am working on a longitudinal survey and need to use conditional logic to create fields for our API data pull. There are two scenarios where I need this to work:

Phone: return mobile_phone if available, otherwise return primary_phone.
Current Address: return the most recently entered address

ZIP field, working
Phone field, not working (returns blank)
The calculated field for ZIP code works properly:

if( isblankormissingcode([2_year_arm_1][zip_2]),
if(isblankormissingcode([18_month_arm_1][zip_2]),
if(isblankormissingcode([1_year_arm_1][zip_2]),
if(isblankormissingcode([6_month_arm_1][zip_2]),
[application_arm_1][zip],
[6_month_arm_1][zip_2]),
[1_year_arm_1][zip_2],
[18_month_arm_1][zip_2]),
[2_year_arm_1][zip_2])

However, I cannot get the phone numbers and address string fields to populate. For these I'm adding a Text Box field and using @-CALCTEXT as an Action Tag.
Since the address formulas incorporate multiple arms, I am hoping to solve this for phone so I'm able to apply that solution for the address string fields. This is my current version for phone (only entered on the application form, application_arm_1):

@CALCTEXT(if ([mobile_phone]!='',
[mobile_phone],
[primary_phone]
)
)

I have tried every possible solution I can think of, including:

Creating it as a calculated field instead
Adding ":value" (e.g., [mobile_phone:value])
Including the instrument arm both with and without ":value" (e.g., [application_arm_1][mobile_phone])
Moving @CALCTEXT inside the logic formula to calculate each component of the formula
Concat([mobile_phone],[primary_phone]) - with and without CALCTEXT, :value, arms
Using "isblankormissingcode()" instead of " !='' "
I also tried all of the above with just a single phone field and no calculation.

Everything so far simply returns a blank where test data is known to contain responses. What can I try next?
